# VBA to convert amount to words except for cents

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the codes below, how can I edit this so the cents will remain numeric.
Instead of converting Cents to text, I want it to show Cent amount over 100 (10.21 > Ten Dollars & 21/100).

> Example:
>   **$50.31** convert to **Fifty Dollars & 31/100**.
>   **$50.00**  convert to **Fifty Dollars Only**
>   **$50.01**  convert to **Fifty Dollars & 1/100**

(Sorry for bad english).

```
'Main function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
ReDim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = " Thousand "
Place(3) = " Million "
Place(4) = " Billion "
Place(5) = " Trillion "
' String representation of amount.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
              "00", 2))
    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If
Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
    Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
    If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
    If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
        MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
    Else
        MyNumber = ""
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred and "
End If
' Convert the tens and ones place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If
GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
Dim Result As String
Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
    Select Case Val(TensText)
        Case 10: Result = "Ten"
        Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
        Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
        Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
        Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
        Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
        Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
        Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
        Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
        Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
        Case Else
    End Select
Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
    Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
        Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
        Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
        Case 4: Result = "Forty "
        Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
        Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
        Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
        Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
        Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
        Case Else
    End Select
    If GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) = "" Then
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1))   ' Retrieve ones place.
        Else
         Result = Result & "-" & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1))
    End If
End If
GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
Select Case Val(Digit)
    Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
    Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
    Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
    Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
    Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
    Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
    Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
    Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
    Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
    Case 0: GetDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
          "00", 2))
```

to

```
Cents = " " & Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "/100"
```

BTW, you should declare types of variables, like

```
Dim Dollars As String, Cents As String, Temp As String
```